# structure design styles

Tags: c#, datagridview, format

I want to show a `DataGridView` as a theater's structure design in windows c#. I don't know how to do it, I have searched for it so far but i have not found any specific styles.

The design is stored database and according to that data, the design should display in datagrid.

For example, see the attached image, I want to do like that:

[image: 1vHn4.jpg]

Comment: What do you mean specific styles? What exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: are you talking about layout you would wrap the seat icons in ?

Comment: you have to draw a chair :D

Comment: Better to do it with some drawing. DataGridView is not for this purpose.

Comment: @ryadavilli 'm a new on this site.. I want a look of datagridview same as image except i don't want that chairs. Suppose, consider the above image. There are character "A" to "U" named rows and every row have a different no. of columns. Consider one seat in image, as one cell of grid. I have a table in database same as physical structure like rownumber, column1 to column15(i.e. 15 seats in one row, but in some row, there is a passage, entry point or exit point, etc).

Comment: @canahari so,  what can i do?? please tell me...if you are not able to understand then i can tell you again...please reply

Answer (score 0):

Is creating a table possible?

Read the data from the database

Per row, add a TableRow.
Per seat, add a TableCell.
Insert whatever you like in the cell

```
TableCell.Text
```

For the Passages, you could enter empty cells/rows but you need to know the place.

Then append the table to a placeholder or your page

```
Page.Controls.Add(Table);
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Table);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i wanna do it in windows form. So, tell me how to do it with windows form.